How do 2 beaker electrolytic cells work?
I've never seen a 2 cell eletrolytic cell before.
I am comfortable with how a 1 cell (standard) electrolytic cell works. But I have never seen this before:


Electrodes P and Q are made of metal M.
Electrodes R and S are made of graphite.

The question asks us to find the polarity of X and Y, given that the ratio of the volume of gases produced at R and S is 2:1 respectively.
X is meant to be -ve. I was trying to understand the mechanism but it makes no sense.
That means at P, we are seeing reduction occuring:
$$\ce{M^{2+}_{(aq)} + 2e- -> M_{(s)}}$$
But then what is the point of Q?
$\ce{M^{2+}_{(aq)}}$ ions would move towards P, and hence Q would become negative. I imagine that wire between Q and R is meant to conduct electrons. Does that mean Q is being oxidised? Why is it oxidised?

There is no such things as a two-cell electrolytic cell. But batteries of two or more electrolytic cells are common, better utilizing power sources with high available voltage but limited maximal current. // cells are fully independent on each other and can be evaluated as if the other cell were an ordinary voltage-dependent resistance.

John Hon, if you show more effort, then I will write an answer, but can you connect this diagram with the fact that it is two electrolytic cell connected in series? Assign the sign of anode and cathode in an electrolytic cell.

The first cell is a coulometer; it measures integrated current. Silver is usually the metal and ions.  The second is the actual electrolysis. it seems you must infer the actual reaction. To conduct both cells must have an oxidation and reduction reaction at their respective electrodes.
